# How to intercept/listen for all json / pojo conversions with Jackson Json?

Tags: java, json, debugging, jackson, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jackson 2.5 for JSON conversion to/from POJOS together with Jersey 2.x. I provide to Jersey an `ObjectMapper` that is then used for all POJO/JSON conversions.

Is there a way to register some sort of global listener on `ObjectMapper` or somewhere else in Jackson so I could debug all Json that is read or written by it?

I'm looking for a way to debug all conversions whether they are from or to Json hava could be performed using a given `ObjectMapper`, but after extensive research I couldn't find a way.

If this is possible and you can help me find out how, I'd greatly appreciate.

Thanks!

**UPDATE: ** I'm aware of Jersey's `LoggingFilter`, but it doesn't work with my compression interceptor and ends up logging compressed content no matter what.. so after expending some good hours on it I moved on.

Comment: [JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers) might help you.

Comment: I wouldn't do it at the `ObjectMapper` level. Create a servlet `Filter` and check request/response content.

Comment: I did it that way for incoming data (read the input stream in a filter when debug is enabled, log content and reset stream before proceeding), but in the case of outgoing data I can't do it over there as far as I can tell.. filters request seem to run before data is marshalled into json. I'd like to get that json and log it too when debug level is set to a fine level.